# Linq to sql, unable to separate query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

So after a lot of toil i found im having a problem executing queries from other queries using linq to sql. Look below to how i had it the way i liked it. When i did this, I got a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error. Finally I have a feeling its because of how i store the queries in a variable. NotDownloadedIds is just a filtered table, so I store it in an `Iqueryable <tableName>`. This way i can pass it into a method.  This is the ugly query i got to work:

```
 var storesLeft = (from x in cDataContext.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappings
 join y in cDataContext.Categories
 on x.CategoryID equals y.CategoryID
 where (y.StorefrontID == 73) 
 && !(
   from ndID in
   (
   from b in cDataContext.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappings
   where 
   !(
     from dll in cDataContext.DownloadLogs
     where dll.DTS.Hour == DateTime.Now.Hour

     select dll.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID)
     .Contains(b.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID)
     select b)
   select ndID.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID)
 .Contains(x.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID)
 select x);
```

What i want to do is seperate some of those froms into other queries. something like:

```
 var storesLeft = (from x in cDataContext.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappings
 join y in cDataContext.Categories
 on x.CategoryID equals y.CategoryID
 where (y.StorefrontID == 73) &&
 !(from ndID in notDownloadedIds
 select ndID.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID)
 .Contains(x.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID)
  select x);
```

where notDownloadedIds looks like:

```
  (from x in cDataContext.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappings
   where !(from dll in cDataContext.DownloadLogs
   where dll.DTS.Hour == DateTime.Now.Hour
    select dll.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID)
   .Contains(x.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID)
    select x);
```

Any thoughts on why the first works, and the other 2 doesn't? Is there anything I can do to make the query look like the second 2?

EDIT: to explain what this query does in the first place. Not downloadedIds gets all the cccMappings(categoryCountryCategoryTypeMappings) where the row time stamp matches the current hour, and its the cccMapings are not found in my current logs.

Comment: Okay, so what have you tried so far?  Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Sorry, i made an edit making my question clearer. I want to seperate the query as showin in the second code block, which would make notDownloadedIds look like it does in the 3rd. But this causes a null exception error

Comment: Also i made the exception thrown more clear

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Also, the indentation is pretty bad and that makes the code hard to read.

Comment: Id take an edit suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely refactor the query to make it more readable, understandable and concise. You can e.g replace

```
 (from dll in cDataContext.DownloadLogs
 where dll.DTS.Hour == DateTime.Now.Hour

 select dll.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID)
 .Contains(b.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID)
```

with

```
cDataContext.DownloafLogs.Any(dll => 
    dll.DTS.Hour == DateTime.Now.Hour && 
    dll.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID == b.CategoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingID
)
```

because it is really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve with the query above.

Comment: yes but that is a small refactoring. It  helps, but i mean to query against a query. Especially since other queries will use notdownloadedIds. Ill add an edit to the original post to explain what the query is doing.

Comment: In a way this helped me relook at my code. In my confusion i screwed up what i was trying to do. Im not sure what i was even doing. I refactored and it works fine and looks clean.

Comment: Georg, I whould remove word *more* from your first sentence :)